# Cannot import name <MyClass> in Python

Tags: python

I try to import a class in python but I get some trouble probably because of cyclic import but I don't know how to solve my problem.

The loop that appears in my traceback (packageA contains three files: A, B and C):

```
**In main.py**    
from packageA import fileA
**In fileA.py:**
from packageA import fileB    <- 
**In fileB.py:**
from packageA import fileC
**In fileC.py:**
from fileB import ClassB      <-
```

I get:

```
ImportError: cannot import name ClassB
```

At first, I thought that I could delete **"import ClassB"** from fileC as the whole fileB had already been imported before. But if I try so I get another error which is:

```
NameError: global name 'ClassB' is not defined
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

This is a case of [circular imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python).  fileB is importing fileC, which is importing fileB.  The latter import is being satisfied with an empty, uninitialized module object.

In general, you do not want to use circular imports.